# How to close android webview from webpage opened in webview?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, android-webview

I have an android application and I am opening a web page in webview.

When my process on that webpage completes, I am giving there a simple html 'close' link/button in that webpage. I want to close the opened webview by an action in webpage.

Can I achieve this by window.close button? Please guide me how can I close webpage/webview through a webpage?

Also this method will work in iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView the basis upon which you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online content within your Activity.  so whenever you will finish your activity in which you are displaying webview in that case webview will be closed.
For more info read the documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Nagendra, I want to close webview when my activity will get completed, I need to do it from webpage opened in webview. Outside it no one can know whether activity is completed or not?

Comment: I don't think so it is possible to close the webview from the webpage because it is the part of the activity .

Comment: My pleasure Maulik but If you found my answer help full please vote for it